# How to delete node from XML column in DB

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, dml

I am trying to remove a particular "node" from an XML column in my SQL Table.
Below is an example of one of the XML column contents.

```
<GodBrandConfig>
  <AppSecret>hello</AppSecret>
  <WebClientUrl>url</WebClientUrl>
  <AllowableIpAddresses>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>.*</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>178.160.245.88</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>178.160.245.88</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
  </AllowableIpAddresses>
  <GameplaySummaryUrl>about:blank</GameplaySummaryUrl>
</GodBrandConfig>
```

I am trying to delete duplicate records in here - For example "    178.160.245.88"

I have been trying many variations of the "delete" statement - Please can i have some assistance on this.
`set column.modify('delete /GodBrandConfig/AllowableIpAddresses/"178.160.245.88")') where idcolumn= 1125;`

Comment: (1) Is `000.000.000.000` not considered as duplicate? It appears a few tens times. and (2) how do you deal with a value like `.*` ?

Comment: Ignore them - I was just "blanking" those IP's out.
I have stripped the XML to only include the values i am trying to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select an `AllowableIpAddress` node in your XPath, and since you're wanting to remove a duplicate you can delete the second occurrence that matches the specified text using something like:

```sql
update #DemoTable
set [column].modify('delete /GodBrandConfig/AllowableIpAddresses/AllowableIpAddress[text()="178.160.245.88"][2]')
where idcolumn = 1125;
```

Which yields the updated XML:

```xml
<GodBrandConfig>
    <AppSecret>hello</AppSecret>
    <WebClientUrl>url</WebClientUrl>
    <AllowableIpAddresses>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>.*</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>178.160.245.88</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
        <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    </AllowableIpAddresses>
    <GameplaySummaryUrl>about:blank</GameplaySummaryUrl>
</GodBrandConfig>
```

Comment: (1) This clean only specific IP which you know in advance that is duplicated. (2) This only remove the second entity of the duplicated but what if you have more than two duplicated values?!? I see that this answer was selected as fit to the OP but I think that this is a mistake. Therefore, I will add another answer which cover all cases and remove nodes with duplicate values, for the sake of future readers `:-)`

Comment: Note: if you want to remove all the nodes except the first one and not only the second one then you can use `[position() > 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Check if this fit your needs

```
DECLARE @myDoc XML
SET @myDoc = '<GodBrandConfig>
  <AppSecret>hello</AppSecret>
  <WebClientUrl>url</WebClientUrl>
  <AllowableIpAddresses>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>.*</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>178.160.245.88</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>178.160.245.88</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
    <AllowableIpAddress>000.000.000.000</AllowableIpAddress>
  </AllowableIpAddresses>
  <GameplaySummaryUrl>about:blank</GameplaySummaryUrl>
</GodBrandConfig>'  

-- Create clean node without duplication using "distinct-values"
DECLARE @AllowableIpAddress XML
SELECT @AllowableIpAddress = (
    SELECT @myDoc.query('
    <AllowableIpAddresses>
           {
                  for $x in distinct-values(//AllowableIpAddress/text())
                  return <AllowableIpAddress>{$x}</AllowableIpAddress>
           }
    </AllowableIpAddresses>
    ')
)

-- "replace node" is not supported in T-SQL (it is supported in oracle)
-- Therefore I will use modify with the actions "delete" and "insert"  
SET @myDoc.modify('delete (/GodBrandConfig/AllowableIpAddresses)')
SET @myDoc.modify('insert sql:variable("@AllowableIpAddress") after (/GodBrandConfig/WebClientUrl)[1]')
SELECT @myDoc ;
```

Comment: Notice that I removed all duplicated including the zero IP "000.000.000.000" as you said that this was added only for the sake of the question to fill the data and it is duplicated